# Mass Transit, with multiple job consumer instance

Tags: .net-6.0, masstransit

I am trying to wrap my head around Masstransit's Sagas, JobConsumers etc with multiple instances.

I am using MassTransit v8 in .net6 over rabbitmq.

The basic idea is that I have a service svcA that will maintain a Saga to orchestrate a request.
This saga needs to be able to Send() to a specific instance of a service svcB that runs a JobConsumer.
What I am trying to achieve, though, is to have several instances of SvcA and SvcB, trying to configure a specific endpoint for each JobConsumer in each SvcB instance. SvcA, in turn, will Send() to the proper instance through configuration.

The idea is that each instance of SvcB will update a specific database, and each instance of SvcA knows which service instance of svcB to address for that (if that makes sense).

I almost managed to get it to work using a different prefix in the KebabEndpointNameFormatter on svcB, which gives me different exchange/queue names quite simply (although I am not sure this is the proper way...).

However, when I Send() the reqA, work happens properly on the correct instance of SvcB, but I see failures on the other instance, probably because the Job system publishes by contract and this instance sees events not correlated to actual jobs.

I think I am going at it the wrong way, but I can't figure out how to configure this...
Does my architecture make sense ? (one service providing JobConsumer endpoints deployed in different instances on different endpoints that are sent to depending on configuration).
Is there a way to make the JobConsumer system do that ? If so, how ? What will the uri be for the Send() operation in the saga ?

There seems to be several issues with my line of thinking but MassTransit is not that easy to approach for a messaging beginner (with great power comes great complexity, I guess...).

Any pointers ?

Comment: You're asking a complex question with words, code speaks more clearly. If you have a standalone repository, I'd suggest creating a discussion on the MassTransit GitHub repository to sort through it.

Comment: good point. I'll try to come up with a simple example of my problem and post it there.